# Issue with WhatsApp Cloud API Upload: Receiving "invalid_request" Error due to Incorrect MIME Type

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, media, whatsapp-cloud-api

I encountered an issue while trying to upload an image to the WhatsApp Cloud API using Axios. Despite setting the content type of the form data to `image/png` for an image with a `.png` extension, I keep receiving an error message from WhatsApp indicating an `invalid_request`. The error message specifically mentions that *the parameter "file" must be a file with one of the specified MIME types,* but it's receiving a file of type "application/octet-stream".

The error message received from WhatsApp is:

> OAuth 'Facebook Platform' 'invalid_request' '(#100) Param file must be a file with one of the following types:
> audio/aac, audio/mp4, audio/mpeg, audio/amr, audio/ogg, audio/opus, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/pdf, text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, image/jpeg, image/png, image/webp, video/mp4, video/3gpp. Received file of type 'application/octet-stream'

[image: Here is the screen shot of pipdream post request]

Here is code for the node.js file

```js
(async () => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("messaging_product", "whatsapp");
      formData.append("type", "image/png");
      const stream = await streamToBlob(
        fs.createReadStream(
          "/filepath"
        )
      );
      formData.append("file", stream);

      console.log("formData", formData);
      let config = {
        method: "post",
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        url: `https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/${phoneNumberId}/media`,
        headers: {
          Authorization:
            `Bearer ${token}`,
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data;image/png",
        },
        data: formData,
      };

      axios
        .request(config)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    })();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Despite setting the content type of the form data to "image/png" for an image with a .png extension

You have added an extra *parameter* with the name `type`, and the value `image/png` - which has nothing whatsoever to do with the actual `Content-Type` of anything else.

And you have set `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;image/png`, which simply makes no sense. The Content-Type of the *request* needs to be just `multipart/form-data`. `image/png` is only the Content-Type of one of the *parts* inside this multipart request.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-to-blob shows that `streamToBlob` takes an optional second parameter, `mimeType` - and that is where you need to set the Content-Type for the BLOB that you are creating here.

```
const stream = await streamToBlob(
        fs.createReadStream(
          "/filepath"
        ),
        "image/png"
      );
```